# Why K-map has states in sequence of 00,01,11,10 instead of 00,01,10,11?

Tags: digital, digital-logic

Why K-map has states in sequence of 00,01,11,10 instead of 00,01,10,11?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code

Answer (score 9):

It's because in the first sequence, each entry differs in only one bit whereas in the second sequence the transition from 01 to 10 changes two bits which produces a race condition. In asynchronous logic, nothing ever happens at the same time, so 01 to 10 is either 01 00 10 or 01 11 10 and that causes problems.

Answer (score 0):

In the process of simplification, when 2 minterms, with one bit differing,r ORed, one variable gets eliminated as 1 + 0 = 1

Answer (score 0):

This is because if we write 00 01 11 10 then in between two there is a difference of two bits and as smparkes told that asynchronous cannot take two values a time so that is the only way left now. As we take gray code in a similar way gray code of 00 is 00, of 01 is 01, of 11 is 10 and of 10 is 11. In this way k map is numbered.